# How to use Assumptions in a Series Expansion

Tags: series-expansion, assumptions

I want to series expansion the expression $\frac{1}{2} \left(e_1+e_2-\sqrt{e_1^2-2e_1e_2+e_2^2+4V_{12}^2} \right)$ up to second order in $V_{12}$ using the assumption $e_1>e_2$. So I tried

```
Series[1/2 (e1 + e2 - Sqrt[e1^2 - 2 e1 e2 + e2^2 + 4 V12^2]), {V12, 0, 2}, 
Assumptions -> e1 > e2] // FullSimplify
```

But there is still $\sqrt{(e_1-e_2)^2} $ terms in the results. What should I do to make the assumption $e_1>e_2$ work?

Comment: You have to enter the expression in *Mathematica* code, not TeX code.

Comment: @MichaelE2 fyi, Wolfram alpha was smart enough to parse part of this command even in Latex! It gave back `Series Sqrt`, ok not exactly the full command, but very impressive none-the-less ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iUaip.png)  may be in the future with more AI it will be able to process full latex input as well.

Comment: @Nasser `ToExpression["\\frac {1} {2}\\left (e_ 1+e_ 2- \\sqrt {e_ 1^2-2 e_ 1 e_ 2+e_ 2^2+4 V_ {12}^2} \\right)", TeXForm]`  -- have to add the extra backslashes by hand, I guess. :(

Comment: I only enter the tex code for display purpose. Thank you anyway!

Comment: But "display purpose" is not nearly as useful as cut-and-pasteable, if people are to attempt any diagnosis.

Comment: @Nasser If I paste the TeX into a string, *Mma* will insert the extra backslashes.  (Forgot about that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Assumptions` given to `Series` are not used by `FullSimplify` that you have in your code.

To pass `Asumptions` to all functions in given expression, wrap said expression with [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assuming.html):

```
Assuming[e1 > e2,
    Series[1/2 (e1 + e2 - Sqrt[e1^2 - 2 e1 e2 + e2^2 + 4 V12^2] ), {V12, 0, 2}] // Simplify
]
(* e2 + V12^2/(-e1+e2) + O[V12]^3*)
```

Or, if you want to always use those assumptions in given session, assign them to [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24Assumptions.html):

```
$Assumptions = e1 > e2;
Series[1/2 (e1 + e2 - Sqrt[e1^2 - 2 e1 e2 + e2^2 + 4 V12^2] ), {V12, 0, 2}] // Simplify
(* e2 + V12^2/(-e1+e2) + O[V12]^3*)
```

Comment: Yeah, that make sense! awesome reply!

Answer (score 1):

If we remove the subscripts from the converted TeX,

```
ToExpression[
 "\\frac{1}{2} \\left(e_1+e_2-\\sqrt{e_1^2-2e_1e_2+e_2^2+4V_{12}^2} \\right)",
 TeXForm] /. Subscript[b_, e_] :> b[e]
(*
  1/2 (e[1] + e[2] - Sqrt[e[1]^2 - 2 e[1] e[2] + e[2]^2 + 4 V[12]^2])
*)
```

we can simply use [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PowerExpand.html):

```
Series[
 1/2 (e[1] + e[2] - Sqrt[e[1]^2 - 2 e[1] e[2] + e[2]^2 + 4 V[12]^2]),
 {V[12], 0, 2}] // PowerExpand
(*
  e[2] - V[12]^2 / (e[1] - e[2]) + O[V[12]]^3
*)
```

**Edit**: [I should have been more careful](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PowerExpand.html#150485188):

```
PowerExpand[
 Series[1/2 (e[1] + e[2] - Sqrt[e[1]^2 - 2 e[1] e[2] + e[2]^2 + 4 V[12]^2]), {V[12], 0, 2}],
 Assumptions -> e[1] > e[2]
 ]
(* same as above *)
```

See the link for the explanation in the [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PowerExpand.html#150485188) documentation.

Comment: I can convert my code between mathematica and Tex! That's really cool! Thanks! However, how comes it got the correct answer without the assumption e[1]>e[2], is this implicit in using the functions?

Comment: @KevinPowell That was my sloppiness and my luck.  The link explains it.  `PowerExpand` just picks one way if the assumptions are not specified.  I should have specified the assumptions.